# how to split a dataframe into several ones but grouping similar rows in the same ones?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with more than 20k rows. As follows an example of my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1234", "edje", "hgt1", "4567", "0900", "wwwl", "yyyt", "5789", "hlkk", "3333"),
  group = c("V1", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V3", "V3", "UN", "UN", "UN")
)
```

Now I would like to split this dataframe into 10 dataframes, more or less with a similar amount of rows,
and then I would like to put rows having the same value at the group column in the same dataframe, except for those showing "UN" at group
column, as those rows should be distributed randomly across all 10 dataframes.

I would like to have something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1234", "edje", "5789"),
  group = c("V1", "V1", "UN")
)


df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("hgt1", "4567", "0900", "hlkk"),
  group = c("V2", "V2", "V2", "UN")
)


df3 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("wwwl", "yyyt", "3333"),
  group = c("V3", "V3", "UN")
)
```

But in my case I would like to divide my df in 10 dataframes. How can I do this operation in R?

Comment: Is more than one UN per df permitted? Are there less UN rows than groups?

Comment: I am confused by your text description of 10 data frames, and your desired output only showing three data frames. Are you saying that with the example data, you would want three dfs (since there is V1-V3) but in your real data you would want 10? Or are you saying you want 10 df from these example data with three groups? Also - can data frames have zero UN rows?

Comment: yes more than one UN are allowed per df and there are more UN rows than groups

Comment: It's just an example with three dataframes, but in real data I have 4156 different groups to be split into 10 different dataframes

Answer (score 5):

Here, I first make a vector of permissable, non-"UN" groups. Then I make a new grouping where the "UN" rows are assigned one of those at random, and then split by that new grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
grps <- unique(df$group)
grps <- grps[grps != "UN"]
df %>%
  mutate(group2 = if_else(group == "UN", 
                          sample(grps, nrow(df), replace = TRUE),
                          group)) %>%
  split(.$group2)
```

---

EDIT- OP has specified that their real problem has >4000 groups which they want to split into 10 similarly sized data frames. Here's an alternate example with 26 groups of wildly different sizes (plus some "UN" which are reassigned), which we place into 10 similarly sized groups.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = ids::adjective_animal(n = 400),
  group = sample(c(letters, "UN"), 400, replace = TRUE, prob = 27:1)
)
```

Then we can do the same step as above, but then also assign the 26 groups into 10 bins:

```
grps <- unique(df$group)
grps <- grps[grps != "UN"]

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(group2 = if_else(group == "UN", 
                          sample(grps, nrow(df), replace = TRUE),
                          group))

counts <- count(df2, group2)
df3 <- df2 |>
  left_join(counts |>
              bind_cols(bin = adagio::bpp_approx(counts$n, cap = 42)$xbins))
```

Just to check, these bins are similarly sized, even though we have 26 groups of widely varying size.

```
count(df3, bin)

   bin  n
1    1 42
2    2 42
3    3 42
4    4 41
5    5 39
6    6 42
7    7 40
8    8 40
9    9 39
10  10 33
```

Comment: Thanks! In this way I have a list with as many dataframes as the group stored in the df$group column and with UN rows randomly distributed. How could I then create 10 different dataframes in which distributing group2?

Comment: You might add `%>% list2env(envir=.GlobalEnv)` as a last step to convert the list into separate data frames in the global environment. I would caution that for most purposes it would be cleaner and safer and easier to maintain if you keep the related dataframes in a list.

Comment: By what logic would you want your 4156 groups to be split into only 10 different data frames? This process and logic is not clear from your example.

Comment: they should be split into 10 dataframes on the basis of the size of each group. Basically the 10 dataframes should have more or lesse the same dimension... some groups have just 2 rows, some others 100 rows... so the 10 dataframes should be more or less similar in terms of number of rows, but the important thing is that rows with the same group value should be within the same dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Roughly the same logic as Jon's answer, but with base R.
Make a variable selectiong the "UN" values, then `split` your data by a variable that `replace`s the "UN" values with a random sample of the remaining groups:

```
##set.seed(1)
sel <- df$group == "UN"
out <- split(
   df,
   replace(df$group, sel, sample(unique(df$group[!sel]), sum(sel), replace=TRUE))
)
out

##$V1
##    ID group
##1 1234    V1
##2 edje    V1
##8 5789    UN
##
##$V2
##    ID group
##3 hgt1    V2
##4 4567    V2
##5 0900    V2
##9 hlkk    UN
##
##$V3
##     ID group
##6  wwwl    V3
##7  yyyt    V3
##10 3333    UN
```

Typically you wouldn't bother with actually assigning the results to separate `data.frame`s `df1`-`dfN`. The alternative is to loop over the list directly if you need to query or make further changes to each `data.frame`, like so using `lapply`:

```
lapply(out, \(x) nrow(x) )
##$V1
##[1] 3
##
##$V2
##[1] 4
##
##$V3
##[1] 3
```

Comment: I love this answer, but this only works when the UN entries are less than the number of non-un variables. In this example, if your have 4 UN entries, the code fails.

Comment: @guasi - if i add `replace=TRUE` to the `sample()` call, this should account for that.

Comment: yes that fixes it. Brilliant single line of code!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `split` one-liner like below

```
split(
  df,
  ~ ifelse(group != "UN",
    match(group, unique(group)),
    cumsum(group == "UN")
  )
)
```

which gives

```
$`1`
    ID group
1 1234    V1
2 edje    V1
8 5789    UN

$`2`
    ID group
3 hgt1    V2
4 4567    V2
5 0900    V2
9 hlkk    UN

$`3`
     ID group
6  wwwl    V3
7  yyyt    V3
10 3333    UN
```

Comment: This only works for this example. If there are more UN entries than there are non-un  groups, new sets will be created that contain only UN entries. Doesn't seem to be what the user is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyverse` you can do something like this.

Remember that distribution of `UN` rows will be on random sampling basis and may not be equal in each group.  Try changing seed and observe this.

**However this should work for as many groups in your `df` as you can have.** Just run the code.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1234", "edje", "hgt1", "4567", "0900", "wwwl", "yyyt", "5789", "hlkk", "3333"),
  group = c("V1", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V3", "V3", "UN", "UN", "UN")
)


# Check that df1 doesn't exists (similarly do for other df..s)
df1 
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'df1' not found

set.seed(2)
df %>% 
  mutate(group2 = map(group, ~{if(.x %in% setdiff(unique(group), "UN")) 
    .x 
    else 
      {sample(setdiff(unique(group), "UN"), 1)}})) %>% 
  group_split(group2, .keep = FALSE) %>% 
  set_names(str_c("df", seq_len(length(.)))) %>% 
  list2env(., envir = .GlobalEnv)

#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

df1
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ID    group
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1234  V1   
#> 2 edje  V1   
#> 3 5789  UN
df2
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   ID    group
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 hgt1  V2   
#> 2 4567  V2   
#> 3 0900  V2   
#> 4 3333  UN
df3
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ID    group
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 wwwl  V3   
#> 2 yyyt  V3   
#> 3 hlkk  UN
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If this serves the purpose, I'll explain the code if need be.